# Magnets and entropy

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

While teaching thermodynamics our chemistry teacher (physics syllabus covers only first law) told us that a process is reversible if and only if no entropy is created.

Coming back to everyday life while playing with magnets we have observed that some substances stay magnetized for a very very long time (that is to say permanently) while others lose their magnetism at a moments notice. Now since magnetism is induced in some materials permanently I conclude that some change in entropy takes place. Now how exactly does magnetism produce a change in entropy on a micro and macro scale ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system in equilibrium corresponds to a *free energy* minimum which is a compromise between a minimum of the internal energy with a maximisation of the entropy. When you introduce, say, an unmagnetised ferromagnet to a magnetic field, alignment of the atomic magnetic moments with the external field reduces the internal energy. So if the field is strong enough (i.e. a great enough reduction in internal energy) then magnetisation can occur at the expense of a decrease in entropy.

Note, however, that the total entropy of the universe does not decrease since you need to use a heat engine (e.g. your arm) to move the ferromagnet through the magnetic field which will itself generate entropy.

Comment: "A system in equilibrium corresponds to a free energy minimum" is true when the system is in contact with a thermostat and Helmholtz free energy is defined as $U-TS$. If the system is in contact with a thermostat *and* with a constant pressure mechanical work source then its Gibbs free energy defined as $U-TS+pV$ is minimized in equilibrium.

Comment: @hyportnex Yes, both are free energies...